# developing Microsoft Sql locally on mac

Tags: sql-server, database, xampp, local

I've got a project where I have to work with Microsoft SQL which is new for me.

I already made a lot with MySQL server and database. Is there a way to developpe on a Mac OSX with a local MS SQL database and XAMPP or something like that?

Comment: sure, datasource are probably existing on mac osx, point to your sql server machine. If you want to install sql server database engine on your computer it's pretty easy, install microsoft windows because a client could work on mac osx but not the engine) at least use a vm

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server's database engine only runs on Windows. You can find a spare Windows box to run it, or host the machine with VMWare Fusion / Parallels.

Oracle [SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html) can serve as a replacement for SSMS on Mac.

Comment: Yes. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/sql-server-connection-viewlet-swf-089886.html

Comment: not true , sql developer withthird party connection has READ-ONLY access... you can not write queries.